# Write PWM with only 8 bit? (Timer2)

Tags: pwm, timers

I have a problem with the Servo library.

I need to read a PPM signal and create a PWM signal of each channel. The problem is that PPM has a higher resolution than PWM so I want to use the 16 bit Timer1 for reading PPM. However the Servo library that writes the PWM signal also uses Timer1.

Is it possible to generate a PWM signal with 8 bit / Timer2? And has someone made an example, or an explanation about, how to do that?

Comment: Yes, there is example in this [Tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SecretsOfArduinoPWM)

Comment: Maybe use the servo library as is, and do the PPM counting with timer2 with some overflow handling.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Arduino [Servo library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/servo) uses Timer1 (and other ones, [depending on Arduino boards](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/ide-1.5.x/libraries/Servo/src/avr/ServoTimers.h)) to manage FastPWM via software interrupts. Timer2 is used by tone() function: be careful if you are using that function.

A good **example using Timer2** to generate PWM is the **[Infrared remote library for Arduino](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote)**. If IR_USE_TIMER2 is defined it will use Timer2. The key code is at [IRremote.cpp](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/IRremote.cpp) where the ISR is managed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example from [my page about timers](http://www.gammon.com.au/timers) of using Timer 2 to output a square wave of 50 kHz:

```C++
const byte LED = 3;  // Timer 2 "B" output: OC2B

const long frequency = 50000L;  // Hz

void setup() 
 {
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);

  TCCR2A = bit (WGM20) | bit (WGM21) | bit (COM2B1); // fast PWM, clear OC2B on compare
  TCCR2B = bit (WGM22) | bit (CS21);         // fast PWM, prescaler of 8
  OCR2A =  ((F_CPU / 8) / frequency) - 1;    // zero relative  
  OCR2B = ((OCR2A + 1) / 2) - 1;             // 50% duty cycle
  }  // end of setup

void loop()
  {
  // do other stuff here
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to generate a PWM signal with 8 bit / Timer2?

yes. I implemented multiple approaches, some on avrs and some on pics but the basic principles are the same: https://dannyelectronics.wordpress.com/2017/02/18/driving-multiple-servos-off-a-pic-timer2-ranged-extended/

that post provided a list of links to other implementations - one of them off a timer 2 on avr.